# Delphi IRC Component

Tags: delphi

Are there any fully functional IRC Components out there for Delphi? I have looked at the TIDIRC component (Indy 10), and it is missing too many things to be usable for me.

I basically have an application and I would like to add in the IRC functionality to it, to automatically connect to an IRC server and join 2 channels and allow the participants to interact on those 2 channels. I initially set up the a test application using TIDIRC, and connected to the IRC server, and joined a channel. Unfortunately IDIRC would not return the names of the participants of the channel, and it kept generating 200 errors, and a fair amount of the data returned from the server is being cut. I need to get this up and running quickly and I do not have the time to sit and debug the Indy component and build everything into it, would be nice but not possible at this time.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at:

1. Torry's page on [IRC components for Delphi](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=217)
2. Instructions on building an IRC client [here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Delphi-Kylix/Building-an-IRC-Client/). Plenty of useful information.

Comment: I actually used the building an IRC client tut, and that was how I discovered that there was a number of missing commands etc in the TIDIRC client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library such as [Synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php) and implement your own.  Start with the telnet class, create a new descendant to implement the specific commands you want to provide.  The good thing is that the IRC protocol is well [documented](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2812.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is opensource Delphi client - VisualIRC
http://www.visualirc.net/download.php

Outdated somehow (but same is IRC, no?), but still can be used as root.

To me, the problem with IRC is lack of standard.
The standard features are too narrow and simplistics.
The richer and flexier ones - just simplge login/password authentification - are provided by different and incompatible extenstion. How should u support them all and select the applicable one from the list ?

Answer (score 0):

TIdIRC is actually not free of some smaller Bugs but Indy10 supports you also as a big InternetFramework - you can get Indy10 TIdIRC right running up to Win10:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70O4gkLy_ZY&t=140s

Elmar Baumann